# Is there a way to block raceconditions in php script execution from different users on the same script?

Tags: php

i have a little game (php + sql), where users can attack each other. The most important aspect is to "react" on your opponents skillset, which might take 1 second if youre good. 
Players have managed to attack as groups and force the attack of multiple attacks in this exact 1 second (which is no fun for the opposite player, who cant react on all of them simultaniously).

I have managed to solve the problem from the database perspective, thats not the issue anymore. But i would like to prevent those players from executing the script with that little time in between ANOTHER player (to give the "defender" the time to react).

-- Imagine a Game of Rock Paper Scissor, where you have 1 second to change your hand, but have 5 opponents at the same time.

How could i delay the execution (or prevent it from executing) when the above problem happens?

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You cannot prevent a PHP script from executing. You could delay it, with [sleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php), but I don't think you should.

Comment: If i let the script sleep, it can still be executed with the same script from another player, if they start sleeping at the same time, right? wont do it :/

Comment: You need to utilize locks (or semaphore) - there is a symfony package (called locks) that does exactly provide this feature. Using Sys V Semaphores or file based locks you can do what you want.